# Python - starting the game again

Tags: python

I'm trying to help my son with simple python project. We don't have much of experience so please try to explain simple.
We wrote few questions and once the questions end then if the user would like to play again then it will take him to the beginning...
Can some please help? We are trying to get:
1. If the user will type "yes" then it will take him to the start and the program will start again..
2. If he will type "no" it will give a message :"Thank you...." and if possible will exit/close the screen...

Here is the code:

```
# Starting of the code
import time
import random
def displayIntro():
print('Hello! My name is John. What is your name?')
myname = input()
print ('Well, ' +myname + ' This program is all about skin cancer.')

# some question below

#End of the code
playagain = 'yes'
while playagain == 'yes': 
    displayIntro()
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? You have given us some code and what you want it to do, but you haven't told us what the issue is with your code. Does it not do what you expect it to? Does it throw and exception? If so, what exception - post it in full with the stack trace. Also, check the indentation on your code - is that how it is when you try and run it, or an error in copy/pasting it for SO?

Comment: code is poorly written , what problem you are facing? Actually there are few errors in your code.

Comment: Do you want to restart the script on `yes`? Too bad [goto](http://entrian.com/goto/) isn't part of the language. There are some mistakes in your code, variables `playagain` and `playAgain` shouldn't be mixed-case.

Comment: @Lattyware it was a joke, see the linked page: `The "goto" module was an April Fool's joke, published on 1st April 2004. Yes, it works, but it's a joke nevertheless. Please don't use it in real code!`

Comment: @bouke Didn't see you had a link there, joke went completely over my head.

Answer (score 1):

This will work now. Problems were with indentation and variable names.

**`for python 3.x`** :

```
# Starting of the code

import time
import random
def displayIntro():
    print('Hello! My name is John. What is your name?')
    myname = input()
    print ('Well, ' + myname + ' This program is all about skin cancer.')

    # some question below

#End of the code

playagain = 'yes'
while playagain == 'yes': 
    displayIntro()
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playagain = input()
```

**`for python 2.x`** :

```
# Starting of the code

import time
import random
def displayIntro():
    print('Hello! My name is John. What is your name?')
    myname = raw_input()
    print ('Well, ' + myname + ' This program is all about skin cancer.')

    # some question below

#End of the code

playagain = 'yes'
while playagain == 'yes': 
    displayIntro()
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playagain = raw_input()
```

Comment: i get this error message if i use your code:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LIAM/Desktop/invent with python!/STS Project sun_working on the end.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ('Well, ' + myname + ' This program is all about skin cancer.')
NameError: name 'myname' is not defined

Comment: @VishalD The function in 2.x is `raw_input()` not `raw_data()`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct indenting is essential in Python code. The statements for your function displayIntro need to be indented, otherwise they are not treated as part of the function, and use consistent casing for your variables (playAgain) - Python is case-sensitive:

```
# Starting of the code
import time
import random

def displayIntro():
    print('Hello! My name is John. What is your name?')
    myname = input()
    print('Well, ' +myname + ' This program is all about skin cancer.')

# some question below

#End of the code
playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes': 
    displayIntro()
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Comment: [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) recommends `lowercase_with_underscores` for variables and functions, and `CapWords` for classes - `camelCase` should be avoided. `play_again` would therefore be optimal.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the "playAgain" to "playagain". When i run the module i don't see anything such as: Hello! My name....the shell is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is a little more general, it does answer your specific questions on `y/n` user input and exiting the program.

It's a good idea to separate your program into logical sections using functions. Function may either run some code and return `None` in which case they are referred to as [procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) or they may return something useful.

Then your `main` function ties all your top level functions together. Calling `main()` essentially 'runs the program', which is called inside an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. This if block means: if this script is imported by another module (perhaps to use some of its functions) then don't run main, otherwise 'run the program'.

Top level functions are separated by two blank lines according to Pythons PEP style guide and function names in Python are lowercase with a single underscore separating words.

I also took the liberty of changing `display_intro` to `intro` because the function doesn't solely print text, it also asks for input, although this is mostly trivial, you can name it whatever you like.

Sometimes it's easier to code and to read an infinite while loop using `True` as the loops conditional. In this case `return` or `break` moves execution out of the loop.

```
import time
import random
import sys


def intro():
    print('Hello! My name is John. What is your name?')
    myname = input()
    print ('Well, ' + myname + ' This program is all about skin cancer.')


# some question below


def play_again():
    """Returns True or False"""
    while True:
        # As a convention the capital Y indicates that 
        # hitting enter without any input means yes; yes is default.
        answer = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/n): ")
        if not answer or answer.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
            return True
        elif answer.lower() in ('n', 'no'):
            return False
        else:
            print("Not a valid answer!")


def main():
    while True:
        intro()
        if not play_again():
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I run the code that you added and it is working beside the part which if I click "n" I will get an error message. Any advise? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LIAM/Desktop/invent with python!/STS Project sun 5.py", line 72, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit

Comment: That's not an 'error' in the sense of 'something broke', that's how your program exits. It throws `SystemExit`.

Comment: Well it is not nice when you will get highlighted red code. Is there a way that if I click no - The system will close/terminate the window ?   Thanks!

Comment: Remove `import sys` and `sys.exit()` and you're done. Now when there is no more code left to run, then the program exits and no 'red code'.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is...

```
playagain = 'yes'
while playagain == 'yes': 
    displayIntro()
    playagain = input('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

print('You can move up, down, left or right.')

direction = input('Enter a direction: ')

print('You move ' + direction)

Without all the spaces though